# Most thrilling roller coasters in South Carolina?

Tags: usa, recommendations, amusement-parks, south-carolina

I am going to SC this summer. I wanted to visit some theme/amusement park in the neighborhood (Myrtle Beach) Can anyone suggest decent place with thrilling roller coasters?

I could only find the [South Carolina Best Amusement Parks blog](http://www.bestamusementpark.net/category/best-amusement-parks/south-carolina-best-amusement-parks/), but it doesn't look very trustful

Answer (score 2):

The "[Intimidator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intimidator_%28roller_coaster%29)" is the tallest, fastest, and longest coaster in the southeast. It's located in the [Carowinds Plaza](https://www.carowinds.com/things-to-do/thrill-rides) near Charlotte. They seem to have a massive number of "Thrill rides". It is a bit far away (3+ hours drive) but might be worth for a day trip.

Other parks closer to Myrtle beach are the [Hard Rock Park](http://www.hrpusa.com/), which looks a lot tamer, the [Family Kingdom](http://www.familykingdomfun.com/AmusementPark/index.cfm?RideTypeID=1), which offers a lot of kid-friendly rides but also one [wooden roller coaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Fox_%28roller_coaster%29).

Comment: Thanks for the immediate answer. As for the Family Kingdom I read about it the mentioned above [site](http://www.bestamusementpark.net/family-kingdom-in-myrtle-beach-south-carolina/)